# Why does my excel userform auto close when I click a link

Tags: forms, excel, hyperlink, vba

I have created an excel userform to assist me with my daily duties at work. I've added a page that will include links to information I use regularly.  However, every time I click the link my form closes itself. Is there a way to hinder this?

```
Private Sub LinkTest_Click()
Link = "http://tinyhousetalk.com/"
    On Error GoTo NoCanDo
    ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address:=Link, NewWindow:=True
    Unload Me
    Exit Sub
NoCanDo:
    MsgBox "Cannot open " & Link
End Sub
```

Comment: `Unload Me`????

Answer (score 0):

```
Unload Me
```

This line closes the userform. Simply take that line out and you should be all set. :)

Comment: Since you're new here, please don't forget to mark the answer accepted which helped most in solving the problem.

Comment: Yes please! This will also help me out since I am new as well. Thanks for mentioning this tjb1.

Comment: Scott Craner already provided the answer 30 min before in the comments.

Comment: That's not an answer, it's a comment with no explanation.